# Group strings by similarity to a data.frame

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I'm trying to aggregate entries in a huge database of newspaper articles based on the similarity of the articles themselves.

My data looks somehow like this:

```
ID  Source File Newspaper   Date        Length  Article
1   aaa     The Guardian    07.30.2002  561     US scientist questions 
2   aaa     The Guardian    07.30.2002  426     Cash fine to clear elderly...
3   aaa     The Guardian    07.30.2002  206     Token victory for HIV mother
4   aab     Financial Times 07.29.2002  964     A tough question at the heart..
5   aab     The Guardian    07.29.2002  500     Media: 'We want van Hoogstr…
6   aab     The Mirror      07.29.2002  43      IN BRIEF…
7   aab     The Sun         07.29.2002  196     US scientist questions
8   aab     The Sun         07.29.2002  140     ADDED VALUE
9   aab     The Times       07.29.2002  794     US-scientist questions
10  …       …               …           …       …
```

After looking here for a while I had success with exact duplicates using dplyr:

```
Dup_info <- meta_articles.m %>%
  group_by(Articles) %>%
  summarise(IDs = toString(ID))
```

It correctly identifies #1 and #7 as duplicates and I can keep the info after removing duplicated entries. Unfortunately it does not catch #9 as a duplicate since one single character is different and I don't know dplyr well enough to figure out how to implement a 99% or 95% percent similarity threshold. Does anybody know if this is even possible?

```
dput(meta_articles.m)
structure(list(ID = 1:9, Source.File = c("aaa", "aaa", "aaa", 
"aab", "aab", "aab", "aab", "aab", "aab"), Newspaper = c("The Guardian", 
"The Guardian", "The Guardian", "Financial Times", "The Guardian", 
"The Mirror", "The Sun", "The Sun", "The Times"), Date = c("07.30.2002", 
"07.30.2002", "07.30.2002", "07.29.2002", "07.29.2002", "07.29.2002", 
"07.29.2002", "07.29.2002", "07.29.2002"), Length = c(561L, 426L, 
206L, 964L, 500L, 43L, 196L, 140L, 794L), Article = c("US scientist questions", 
"Cash fine to clear elderly...", "Token victory for HIV mother", 
"A tough question at the heart..", "Media: 'We want van Hoogstr…", 
"IN BRIEF…", "US scientist questions", "ADDED VALUE", "US-scientist questions"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: If you provide the `dput(meta_articles.m)` of the example you could receive more detailed assistance

Comment: You can use `grep` or `pmatch` or `stringdist` to identify partial matches

Comment: You could search for "fuzzy matching" or "clustering" - but nothing like this is built in to dplyr. You could also remove all special characters and convert everything to lower case if you don't want to do anything complicated.

Comment: Look for `adist` as well, which can be used to filter on.

Comment: I would like to provide the meta_articles.m file but its largely material under copyright by different publishers and I'm not sure which of those I could share without trouble (probably nothing of it...)

Comment: I am only referring to the data you posted above. Nothing more. As it is currently posted we cannot copy and paste it into our terminals to help you.

Comment: Ah that's what you meant! Thanks @PierreLafortune

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using a Levenshtein distance metric or something similar to it. This is basically the edit distance between 2 strings. Not going to be perfect, but it'll get you started.

Read more about here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/adist.html

More advanced functions can be found in the `stringdist` package including the `soundex` method allowing for similar-sounding words to be grouped effectively. Also worth looking at is the `RecordLinkage` package.

Without a sizable sample (dput) I cannot provide an implemented example.

Edit:
`adist(meta_articles.m$Article)` will generate a similarity matrix. Ignoring the diagonal, you can parse that matrix to find values at whatever similarity threshold you wish to pursue

```
d <- adist(meta_articles.m$Article)
d2 <- d
d2[d2 > 2] <- NA  #set the limit at distance = 1
d2

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9]
 [1,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA    1
 [2,]   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [3,]   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [4,]   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA   NA
 [6,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA   NA   NA
 [7,]    0   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA    1
 [8,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    0   NA
 [9,]    1   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA    1   NA    0
```

So row [ 1 ] is identical to itself, identical to [7] and at an edit distance of 1 from [9], etc.  You can then move on to clustering by distance, i.e.:

```
d <- adist(meta_articles.m$Article)
rownames(d) <- meta_articles.m$Article
hc <- hclust(as.dist(d))
plot(hc)
```

[image: dendogram]

And finally, grouping together all values with an edit distance of 2 or less:

```
df <- data.frame(meta_articles.m$Article,cutree(hc,h=2))
df

    meta_articles.m.Article cutree.hc..h...2.
1          US scientist questions                 1
2   Cash fine to clear elderly...                 2
3    Token victory for HIV mother                 3
4 A tough question at the heart..                 4
5    Media: 'We want van Hoogstr…                 5
6                       IN BRIEF…                 6
7          US scientist questions                 1
8                     ADDED VALUE                 7
9          US-scientist questions                 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It doesn't yet solve my whole problem but really illustrates the Levenshtein distance part. I'll look into the packages you suggested, they look promising!

Comment: You use variables that are not defined for us. What is `values` and `str`?